# Find Remote IP using .net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i need to find the remote users ip address using asp.net and also i need clarification whether multiusers have same ip address

thanks
Shakthi

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Dim userIP As string = Request.UserHostAddress
> ```

Comment: Thanks Mendy,

its working fine

and it is showing 127.0.0.1 as the remote address

if i use this code in my chat application will it give different ip address for different users

thanks
Shakthi

Answer (score 0):

*Edit* Caveat - the below is talking about an internet scenario. On a more limited (intranet) network, you may be able to assume a 1-1 User-IP Address mapping

Multiple users may appear to have the same IP address.

The same user may make two requests in a row from different IP addresses.

Whatever you're trying to do, using the users IP address for anything other than logging is probably pointless.